# assembly: maximum number: not comparing properly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.data
bigger db 0
mensaje db 0AH,0DH,'Finding the biggest number','$'
mensaje1 db 0AH,0DH,'Write 5 numbers to compare','$'
mensaje2 db 0AH,0DH,'Number: ','$'
resultadomayor db 10,13,'the biggest number is: ','$'
.code
start proc far 
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    mov cx,5
    MOV DX,OFFSET MENSAJE
    MOV AH,09
    INT 21H
    MOV DX,OFFSET MENSAJE1
    MOV AH,09
    INT 21H
ciclo: call iniciociclo
 dec cx
jne ciclo
    call imprimirmayor

    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H  
start endp
;
bucle proc near

 MOV DX,OFFSET MENSAJE2
 MOV AH,09
 INT 21H
 MOV AH,01
 INT 21H
 cmp bigger,al
 jnb masgrande

 masgrande: 
 mov bigger,al
 ret
bucle endp
;
printbiggest proc near

MOV DX,OFFSET resultadomayor
MOV AH,09
INT 21H
mov dx,offset bigger
mov ah,09
int 21h
printbiggest endp
end start
```

When I run my program it just show the biggest as the last number input. It doesn't compare or save the other numbers wrote before the last one. I research to make it as an array, but my teacher is asking me to insert the numbers not to give already the number. The user should give the numbers, not the programmer. So I didn't find how to insert numbers on a array. That's why I did it comparing number to number. By the way this is assembly 8086.

Comment: The code is hard to follow, as you have renamed some procedures, but you haven't changed the names where you call them.

Comment: You still need to change the define for *bigger* to properly display the number in *printbiggest*. Use `bigger db 0,'$'`

Comment: .code
start proc far 
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    mov cx,5
    MOV DX,OFFSET MENSAJE
    MOV AH,09
    INT 21H
    MOV DX,OFFSET MENSAJE1
    MOV AH,09
    INT 21H
ciclo: call iniciociclo
 dec cx
jne ciclo
    call printbigger

    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H  
start endp
;
bucle proc near

 MOV DX,OFFSET MENSAJE2
 MOV AH,09
 INT 21H
 MOV AH,01
 INT 21H
 cmp bigger,al
 jnb masgrande

 masgrande: 
 mov bigger,al
 ret
bucle endp
;
printbiggest proc near

MOV DX,OFFSET resultadomayor
MOV AH,09
INT 21H
mov dx,offset bigger
mov ah,09
int 21h
printbiggest endp
end start

Comment: Thanks i put the $ and it prints better, but still just the last number insert, not the biggest.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
cmp bigger,al
jnb masgrande

masgrande: 
mov bigger,al
```

That code will always copy the value to the variable `bigger`, because the `jnb` instruction doesn't cause any code to be skipped. Rearrange the instructions like this:

```
cmp bigger,al
jnb masgrande
mov bigger,al
masgrande:
```

Comment: It still not comparing numbers. I used cmp bigger,al is to compare between the saved number with the new number. If the new number is bigger then jump to "masgrande", thats the label for mov bigger,al. If the number is not bigger it should do nothing at all.

Comment: @VioletaLeón: The problem with jumping to the code that changes the variable is that the code comes after the jump. If it doesn't jump it will still continue into that code. If you want it to do nothing you need an uncondotional jump or a return to keep it from contiuing into the following code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should put the lines in their correct position, your code just "flew" over the condition (Try to avoid meaningless lables).
Also try using JB instead of JNA.

```
cmp bigger,al
jnb masgrande
;missing
masgrande: 
mov bigger,al

CMP al, biggest
JB NOT_BIGGEST
MOV biggest, al
NOT BIGGEST:
;keep your program here
```